# Debugging SQL CLR code from a C#/ASP.NET application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, debugging, assemblies

I inherited some C# code that creates a DLL that is installed on SQL Server 2005 as a SQL assembly. The following is in the C# code, but how do I get to see this?

```
 #if DEBUG
        JbLog.getInstance().Info(LOG_LEVEL_TYPE.EXTENDED, "Page="+ iPage + ", Row=" + (row + 1));
        JbLog.getInstance().Info(LOG_LEVEL_TYPE.EXTENDED, strQry);
 #endif
```

But how do I use this and how do I trace through the code in the assembly without deploying?

Comment: That's not assembly code you posted. You know that, right? And, what specific problem are you having? What happens when you try to "trace through" it?

Comment: i know thats not assembly code. The only way I test it is too deploy it to my sql server and run the app so that all the store procedures hit the assembly code. Is there an easier way to test this?

Comment: Chris, do you see where in your question you said anything about SQL Server? Could you maybe give some details about what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: You keep talking about assembly code, yet you have not posted assembly, so what assembly code are you talking about exactly?

Comment: i have updated my post, should have been clearer

Comment: Just delete the **#if DEBUG** and **#debug** and insert breakpoints instead.

Comment: how do i run a sql assembly from the ide?

Comment: Obviously, you don't. Deploy it to a "debug" SQL Server instance.

Answer (score 2):

This code is executed when app is running in debug mode. DEBUG is default conditional compilation symbol for debug mode. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691095(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: -1 for posting the ancient link. Please don't do that unless the question is specific to the ancient .NET 1.1 release.

Comment: Oops, but don't think its changed till VS2010. Am I missing something?

Comment: The article is valid.  It doesn't even appear Microsoft has a newer article I certainly could not find it.

Comment: It's not a question of validity. The problem with ancient links is that they link to ancient links, etc. Readers may get lost in a maze of [twisty little links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colossal_Cave_Adventure#Maze_of_twisty_little_passages), all pointing to .NET 1.1 stuff that actually _has_ changed.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - So post the correct article I looked for 20 minutes and could not find an updated article on  conditional compilation symbols.